# Restrict string values in property

Tags: nestjs, prisma

I would like to know how to restrict the possible values in a field in prisma.

My model looks like this currently

```
model FraudOrderCheck {
  id                 Int                  @id @default(autoincrement())
  brand_name         String
  retries            Int                  @default(0)
  validation_state   String               @default('processing') 
}
```

How to restrict the possible values in `validation_state` to this

```
validation_state   String               @default('processing') // processed, errored
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prisma cannot restrict string values at the moment. You would need to handle this in your application logic.

Another workaround would be to use enums:

```
enum ValidationState {
  PROCESSING
  PROCESSED
  ERROR
}
```

Comment: the terrible thing about using ENUM is some database such as postgres is, it does not allow to remove individual item(i.e. PROCESSING) from ENUM type that makes it unusable if you want to make things future proof.